# PyQt: LineEdit widget's placement inside of FormLayout

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, qtgui

A **QtGui.QLineEdit** line_edit widget is placed inside of **QtGui.QFormLayout** Form layout using .addRow() method.

```
my_formLayout.addRow(my_label, my_lineEdit)
```

To make a line_edit widget to stick to a dialog window's edges (so it re-sizes with the dialog) tried using sizePolicy:

```
    sizePolicy = my_lineEdit.sizePolicy()
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
    my_lineEdit.setSizePolicy( sizePolicy )
```

There are no errors. But the line_edit widget still doesn't stick to the edges of the dialog... What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything.

This simple example resizes as necessary:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        form = QtGui.QFormLayout(self)
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Label', self)
        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        form.addRow(label, edit)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Dialog()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 50)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPDATE**:

Okay, it seems the behaviour of QFormaLayout *is* platform-dependent. To quote from the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html#details):

> Style based on the Mac OS X Aqua guidelines. Labels are right-aligned, the fields don't grow beyond their size hint, and the form is horizontally centered.

However, there is a [setFieldGrowthPolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html#fieldGrowthPolicy-prop) method, which could be used to over-ride the default behaviour on Mac OSX. So try:

```
    my_formLayout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QtGui.QFormLayout.ExpandingFieldsGrow)
```

or:

```
    my_formLayout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QtGui.QFormLayout.AllNonFixedFieldsGrow)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Unfortunately your examples keeps line_edit widget centered within a dialog box. The size of the line_edit widget remains to be the same regardless how large or small the main dialog window gets. I want to stick a right or/and left edge of the line_edit widget to the edge(-s) of dialog box.

Comment: @Sputnix. Did you actually run my example? For me, it works perfectly fine. I'd be surprized if it didn't work the same on all platforms, but I only tried it on Linux.

Comment: Screenshot:                                  https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1676x570q90/837/nw72.png       Running it on Mac OSX.

Comment: @Sputnix. Please see my updated answer for a possible solution.

Comment: You've got it nailed 100%! Terrific job! I went with 'AllNonFixedFieldsGrow' since it made everything resize with the dialog box (even the widgets with .setMinimumWidth(value) ). Once again, great job! And thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `sizePolicy.setHorizontalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding)`

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't work for me. The line_edit widget is still not resizing. Maybe some other clever suggestions?

Comment: I think you should post a working code of what are you doing, just for testing and suggestions, the layouts cant be tricky some times :)